# Sharing exclusive files to docker instances from host

Tags: shell, docker, debian-based

I am mounting host machine directory as a volume into docker to share files from host.

It has a git repository that is being used by all docker instances. I want different docker instances should checkout different branch and use parallely without copying it locally again as it will take more time and storage.

Instead I want common place to share files into docker instances initially and all docker should process it differently and consumes space as any increamental change.

Docker-volume with read/write permission is not seems to be suitable for this use-case, any other way to achieve this ?

Edited:
Currently I am using as a volume but it become common place for all docker instances. If docker-1 checkout branch A, and docker-2 checkout branch B at same time, it is changing files for docker-1.

Comment: Can you please update the question, "how are you currently doing it"? And why do you think `docker volume` can't used?